# I2C to USB converter with interrupt

Tags: usb, i2c, interrupts, touchscreen

I have a touch screen with I2C and interrupt output and I would like to connect this touch screen over a USB cable to a host controller.

I know that it is possible to transfer interrupts on the USB bus with USB interrupt packets. But I did not find a USB-to-I2C converter that supports I2C interrupt transmission to a host. E.g. the [MCP2221](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP2221A-Data-Sheet-20005565E.pdf) has interrupt ability, but only for host wake-up function. The FTDI [FT200XD](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/DS_FT200XD.pdf) USB-to-I2C bridge does not seem to support interrupts at all.

I know that stack exchange is not a product recommendation site, but it seems odd to me that  I can't find a solution for such a general problem. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076472/why-is-not-usb-interrupt-driven).

Comment: What's the model of that screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't need interrupts in the sense you think you need them or can't use them anyway if they don't make sense for the USB adapter chip.

A pin called an interrupt pin is not required to cause an interrupt, it just is named so because it might be used to cause an interrupt if found useful.

If you use a MCU to show itself as a HID touchsceen, you will simply send packets about screen being touched when you need to. And the MCU could use the interrupt pin to start reading of touch data from touch IC. But the MCU can use polling, or it might cause an interrupt to trigger code that will read the touch data. But the USB side does not know or care about the touch chip having an interrupt.

But you can't make the PC to see a USB touchscreen with these chips. They will present them as USB serial ports and custom HID so your program has to deal with USB serial ports and I don't even know how to communicate with the custom HID part of the Microchip device.

Also the FTDI FT200XD is a completely wrong chip for the job, you need I2C master for the touch screen while FT200XD is an I2C slave. The FT200XD does have a "interrupt" or status output which can signal to a master that there is data to read or ready to write more.